# Facebook - Using graph api post on a business page - but everyone sees it - want only users liked can see it

Tags: facebook, api, post, privacy

using an **app** and **graph API** i am trying to post on a **business page**
i got the page token and able to post on the page,  **but** that posts can be seen by **everyone** even a user not even logged into facebook
i am trying to post a message on a page where only **users** who have **liked that page** can see those posts

**I tried**

1> when giving permission (while logging) set the permission as Friends only (in question who can see posts this app post)
2>adding privacy parameter while posting a post (ALL_FRIENDS)

but still the post is public and everyone can see it how to post so only the users who have likes can see it

thank you for everyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a feature of the API - if you don't want logged-out users to see something on a Page, add demographic restrictions to it so only logged in users that meet the restrictions can see the page

Comment: Thank you lgy, will try to add that and see if that works. And will update here about it as well, thanks once again

Comment: that works for all the logged out users, if the user is not logged in facebook than the complete page is not shown to that user and redirected to login page but when once logged in they see all the posts,is there a certain restriction we can put on a page that only a user who have liked that page can see the posts other just see the main page an Not the posts on wall?, thanks for you time and help